# React Native Fetch Request with at Risk Response header

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api

Is there any way to launch a "fetch" to a server that doesn't have the needed "access" response headers?

I've been checking the responses through Browser Networking, those that don't have the "access" headers in their response throw "TypeError: Failed to fetch"

**UPDATE**

I mean when these headers are not available in the response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://normal-website.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Special-Request-Header
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

Comment: please more describe or put some code

Comment: i updated the question with the headers